# Can we have an Off-Topic > Belongs on StackOverflow option?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, migration

I'd like for our users to have the ability to vote to close as off-topic > belongs on Stack Overflow. Almost all of our migrations have gone there and, unfortunately, the current process is confusing. Users have to raise a custom flag in order to perform the same kind of migration they're used to performing seamlessly on SO. The only migration they can request directly is to our own meta, which is an extremely rare occurrence.

Our migration stats are not huge, and are not the reason for the request. Also our rejection stats aren't fantastic, but please note that all of the rejections are from more than 90 days ago and, due to the new close reasons, our regular users have had much discussion and have a clearer understanding of why things should - or shouldn't - get migrated away. I feel that this will be a much more common migration path as our site gets more popular (and the sites do overlap quite a bit - part of the reason our site was moved into the top 5 migration paths *from* SO last year).

We seem to have Shog9's support on this, and Oded also said:

[image]

Comment: That's a great proposal. Many times I wanted to choose SO as a target for my migration, but could do that only from a flag comment.

Comment: Aaron, do we have enough migrations to other sites to merit adding more destinations?  I suspect that Server Fault would be the number 2 migration target from here.

Comment: @NickChammas at this time, I don't think so. In the last 90 days, 2 to SuperUser, and 1 to ServerFault.

Answer (score 10):

This has been implemented by the community team.

[image]